# How to use rabbitmq as a distributed task queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

In my knowledge, rabbitmq is a HA message queue. Is is possible use it as a task queue. 
Some requirement:

1. load balanced should consider the worker node idle resource
2. should dynamic add/del worker thread
3. worker node hot-plugging
4. can dynamice set routing.

As rabbitmq consumer can fetch message and define callback function to handle the message.
it is much possible to do that. But I don't know how to use it flexible,dynamically.

Can you give some example or idea?

Answer (score 4):

In RabbitMQ, if more than one consumers binds to a queue, then messages will be load-balanced in a round-robin fashion.

To better understand, you can read this article.

https://techietweak.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/rabbitmq-a-cloud-based-message-oriented-middleware/

Thanks,
Saravanan S.